# Oracle 12 C Installation Error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I've downloaded oracle 12c on my personal laptop.  Check system compatibility (alls good).  However, towards the end Im getting an error stating "Oracle Services for microsoft transaction server" denied".

Please assist,

Comment: Did you try to ignore this warning/error?

Comment: yes, it now says installation complete. Final status failed.

Comment: Same question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139906/error-installing-oracle-database-client-12c-oraclemtsrecoveryservice-control-u

Answer (score 2):

Googling the error message leads to this as the first result:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ins_20802_oracle_services_for_microsoft_transaction_server_failed.htm

Which basically says to ignore the message and run the Database Configuration Assistant manually to finish configuring the database.

Answer (score 1):

When an installation fails, you should check the installation log for more details.

In my case, the log file said "hostname too long", so I shortened the host name and was able to do a successful install.

Comment: Add more detail, such as where you can find the log. What an error might look like in full, will it be prefixed with `ERROR: ... `?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently and it was regarding `[INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed` error. I think the solution for it will of help in your issue too.

I tried several of the following methods for resolving the issue :-

Disabling Windows UAC
Disabling firewall
Disabling antivirus - mine was a fresh VM, so disabled Windows Defender
Adding localhost IP i.e., 127.0.0.1 to the hosts file etc.
but none of them helped.

At last I found this, which suggested installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) and this solved the problem in a matter of seconds! I just had to click 'Retry' on the installation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have local "Admininstrator" rights on the account that your are installing Oracle into?

The Oracle Universal Installer is trying to create the MTS service and access is being denied. This is why I usually don't take the default install, and use the "custom" install and select the components I want. OUI will then work out the dependencies and install the correct components.

With this type of failure, you should have had an option to "ignore/skip" the error and the installer should continue and install the database objects - you shouldn't need to re-install the database objects as the the MTS service component should install after the data objects are created and they are not reliant on each other. Unfortunately the installer status will still show "failed" because of that one component failing.

Comment: What can I do now. Please assist.